# JPA+Hibernate lançando update sozinho

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate, jpa, jsf-2.2

Olá, tenho um objeto que está gerenciado pelo Hibernate. Em tela, um atributo desse objeto é atualizado o valor e o Hibernate imediatamente dispara um update no banco de dados, sem nem mesmo passar por métodos no *controller* ou da camada de persistência de dados.

Alguém consegue me ajudar com isso?

```html
    <!--MODAL BAIXA DE LANCAMENTO-->
    <div id="modal_baixa_lancamento" class="modal modal-fixed-footer col-xs-12 col-md-10"
         style="height: 620px;max-height: 100%;">
        <h:form prependId="false" id="form_modal_cad_despesa_imediata">
            <h:panelGroup id="body_modal_baixa_lancamento" layout="block" styleClass="modal-content">
                <h2 class="label-title" style="text-align: center">
                    <i class="icon-checkmark-circle"> </i> Pagamento de Despesa
                </h2>
                <div class="divider col-xs-12"></div>
                <div class="row no-margin">
                    <!--Detalhes-->
                    <div class="row">
                        <!--Detalhes-->
                        <div class="col-xs-12 m-b-15">
                            <h2 class="label-title no-margin">
                                <i class="icon-info-circle"> </i> Detalhes
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                        <!--Fornecedor-->
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 form-group">
                            <label>
                                Fornecedor
                            </label>
                            <h:panelGroup id="fornecedoresFiltro" styleClass="form-group" layout="block">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12" style="padding-left: 0px; ">
                                    <div class="fg-line">
                                        <h:inputText id="nomeFornecedor" pt:placeholder="Nome"
                                                     styleClass="form-control" disabled="true"
                                                     value="#{listaContaPagar.contaAPagar.favorecido.nome}"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </h:panelGroup>
                        </div>
                        <!--Descrição-->
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 form-group">
                            <label for="descricao">
                                <span style="color: red">*</span> Descrição
                            </label>
                            <div class="fg-line">
                                <h:inputText id="descricao" pt:placeholder="Digite a descrição"
                                             styleClass="form-control" required="true" process="@this"
                                             requiredMessage="Informe uma Descrição" event="change"
                                             disabled="true"
                                             value="#{listaContaPagar.contaAPagar.descricao}">
                                </h:inputText>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--Data de Vencimento-->
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 form-group">
                            <label for="dataVencimento">
                                <span style="color: red">*</span> Data de Vencimento
                            </label>
                            <div class="fg-line">
                                <h:inputText id="dataVencimento"
                                             styleClass="form-control datetimepicker"
                                             converter="localDateConverter"
                                             disabled="true"
                                             value="#{listaContaPagar.contaAPagar.datasLancamentoFinanceiro.dataVencimento}">
                                </h:inputText>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--Data de Pagamento-->
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 form-group">
                            <label for="dataPagamento"><span
                                    style="color: red">*</span>Data do Pagamento</label>
                            <div class="fg-line">
                                <h:inputText id="dataPagamento"
                                             styleClass="form-control datetimepicker"
                                             converter="localDateConverter"
                                             converterMessage="Data de Pagamento inválida!"
                                             value="#{listaContaPagar.contaAPagar.datasLancamentoFinanceiro.dataBaixa}"
                                             pt:placeholder="__/__/____"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--Numero de Documento-->
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 form-group">
                            <label for="numeroDocumento">
                                Número do Documento
                            </label>
                            <div class="fg-line">
                                <h:inputText id="numeroDocumento" disabled="true"
                                             styleClass="form-control"
                                             value="#{listaContaPagar.contaAPagar.numeroDocumento}"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--Tipo de Documento-->
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 form-group" style="height: 58px;">
                            <label for="tipoDocumentoDespesa">
                                Tipo do Documento
                            </label>
                            <div class="fg-line">
                                <h:inputText id="tipoDocumentoDespesa" disabled="true"
                                             styleClass="form-control"
                                             value="#{listaContaPagar.contaAPagar.tipoDocumento.descricao}"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--Taxa e Valores-->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 m-b-15">
                            <h2 class="label-title no-margin">
                                <i class="icon-dollar-circle"> </i> Taxas e Valores
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                        <!--Valor do Documento-->
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 form-group">
                            <label for="valorDocumento">
                                <span style="color: red">*</span>
                                Valor do Documento
                            </label>
                            <div class="fg-line">
                                <h:inputText id="valorDocumento" converter="#{moneyConverter}"
                                             styleClass="input-money form-control"
                                             pt:placeholder="R$ 0,00" disabled="true"
                                             value="#{listaContaPagar.contaAPagar.valoresLancamentosFinanceiro.valorDocumento}">
                                </h:inputText>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--Juros-->
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 form-group">
                            <label for="valor_juros">
                                Juros
                            </label>
                            <div class="fg-line">
                                <h:inputText id="valor_juros" converter="#{moneyConverter}"
                                             styleClass="input-money form-control"
                                             pt:placeholder="R$ 0,00"
                                             value="#{listaContaPagar.contaAPagar.valoresLancamentosFinanceiro.valorJuros}">
                                    <p:ajax event="blur" process="@this"
                                            listener="#{listaContaPagar.atualizarValorPago}"/>
                                </h:inputText>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--Multa-->
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 form-group">
                            <label for="valor_multa">
                                Multa
                            </label>
                            <div class="fg-line">
                                <h:inputText id="valor_multa" converter="#{moneyConverter}"
                                             styleClass="input-money form-control"
                                             pt:placeholder="R$ 0,00"
                                             value="#{listaContaPagar.contaAPagar.valoresLancamentosFinanceiro.valorMulta}">
                                    <p:ajax event="blur" process="@this"
                                            listener="#{listaContaPagar.atualizarValorPago}"/>
                                </h:inputText>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--Desconto-->
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 form-group">
                            <label for="valor_desconto">
                                Desconto
                            </label>
                            <div class="fg-line">
                                <h:inputText id="valor_desconto" converter="#{moneyConverter}"
                                             styleClass="input-money form-control"
                                             pt:placeholder="R$ 0,00"
                                             value="#{listaContaPagar.contaAPagar.valoresLancamentosFinanceiro.valorDesconto}">
                                    <p:ajax event="blur" process="@this"
                                            listener="#{listaContaPagar.atualizarValorPago}"/>
                                </h:inputText>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--Pagamentos-->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 m-b-15">
                            <h2 class="label-title no-margin">
                                <i class="icon-money"> </i> Pagamentos
                                <p:commandLink styleClass="btn bgm-deeporange btn-icon"
                                               onclick="abrirPagamento();">
                                    <span class="icon-plus"> </span>
                                </p:commandLink>
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <p:dataTable id="tb_pagamentos" widgetVar="tb_pagamentos"
                                         value="#{listaContaPagar.contaAPagar.pagamentos}"
                                         var="pagamento" reflow="true" emptyMessage="Nenhum registro encontrado.">
                                <p:column headerText="Valor" styleClass="text-center">
                                    <h:outputText
                                            value="#{pagamento.valorPago}" converter="#{moneyConverter}">
                                    </h:outputText>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="Meio de Pagamento" styleClass="text-center">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{pagamento.meioPagamento.descricao}"/>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="Conta Financeira" styleClass="text-center">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{pagamento.contaCaixa.nome}"/>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="Situação" style="text-align: center;"
                                          filterable="false" width="5%">
                                    <h:panelGroup
                                            styleClass="#{listaContaPagar.retornaSituacaoPagamento(pagamento)}"
                                            style="width:20px; height:20px; border-radius: 50%; margin:auto;"
                                            layout="block">
                                    </h:panelGroup>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="Ações" styleClass="text-center">
                                    <p:commandLink
                                            action="#{listaContaPagar.verificaPodeEditar}"
                                            immediate="true">
                                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{pagamento}"
                                                                     target="#{listaContaPagar.pagamentoAux}"/>
                                        <span class="icon-pencil"> </span>
                                    </p:commandLink>
                                    <p:commandLink
                                            action="#{listaContaPagar.verificaPodeEstonar}"
                                            immediate="true">
                                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{pagamento}"
                                                                     target="#{listaContaPagar.pagamentoAux}"/>
                                        <span class="icon-rotate_left"> </span>
                                    </p:commandLink>
                                </p:column>
                            </p:dataTable>
                        </div>
                        <h:panelGroup id="valor_aberto_pago" styleClass="col-xs-12">
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-9">
                                <h:outputLabel value="Valor em Aberto: ">
                                    <h:outputText
                                            value="#{listaContaPagar.contaAPagar.valoresLancamentosFinanceiro.valorAberto}"
                                            converter="#{moneyConverter}"/>
                                </h:outputLabel>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-9">
                                <h:outputLabel value="Valor Pago: ">
                                    <h:outputText
                                            value="#{listaContaPagar.contaAPagar.valoresLancamentosFinanceiro.valorPago}"
                                            converter="#{moneyConverter}"/>
                                </h:outputLabel>
                            </div>
                        </h:panelGroup>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </h:panelGroup>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <p:commandLink id="baixar_lancamento" styleClass="btn btn-primary"
                               actionListener="#{listaContaPagar.salvarDespesaImediata}">
                    <i class="icon-file-text"> </i> Salvar Despesa
                </p:commandLink>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-default m-r-15"
                   onclick="$('#modal_baixa_lancamento').closeModal();">
                    <i class="icon-times"> </i> #{msg.btn_cancelar}
                </a>
            </div>
        </h:form>
    </div>
```

Este modal acima carrega um objeto do tipo `LancamentoFinanceiro`, nele posso adicionar uma lista de pagamentos (Valor, conta e meio de pagamento), quando adiciono um pagamento o valor pago no lançamento é alterado. O método abaixo realiza essa alteração:

```java
public void addPagamento() {
    try {
        if (!editarPagamento) {
            if (regraBaixa.nao().satisfeitaPor(pagamentoAux)) {
                throw new RegraDeNegocioExecption(regraBaixa.getDetails());
            }
            if (baixaSimples) {
                contaAPagar = lancamentoFinanceiroService.addPagamento(contaAPagar, pagamentoAux);
                if (contaAPagar.getValoresLancamentosFinanceiro().getValorAberto().doubleValue() < 0) {
                    qMessagesHelper.toastWarning(null, "Valor pago é maior que o valor do documento!", null);
                }
            } else {
                baixaMultiplaLancamento = lancamentoFinanceiroService.addPagamento(baixaMultiplaLancamento, pagamentoAux);
                if (baixaMultiplaLancamento.getValoresLancamentosFinanceiro().getValorAberto().doubleValue() < 0) {
                    qMessagesHelper.toastWarning(null, "Valor pago é maior que o valor do documento!", null);
                }
            }
            pagamentoAux = new Pagamento();
        } else {
            editarPagamento = Boolean.FALSE;
            contaAPagar.getValoresLancamentosFinanceiro().setValorPago(
                    lancamentoFinanceiroService.retornaSaldoPago(contaAPagar)
            );
            contaAPagar.getValoresLancamentosFinanceiro().setValorAberto(
                    lancamentoFinanceiroService.calculaVlrAberto(contaAPagar)
            );
            meioCartao = Boolean.FALSE;
        }
        //Updates nos Componentes
        if (baixaSimples) {
            facesUtil.updateComponente("tb_pagamentos panelPagamentos valor_aberto_pago");
        } else {
            facesUtil.updateComponente("baixaMultipla_tb_pagamentos panelPagamentos valor_aberto_pago_multipla");
        }
        facesUtil.executeScriptJS("ativaScripts();$('#modal_cad_pagamento').closeModal();");
    } catch (RegraDeNegocioExecption e) {
        for (QimobAlert s : e.getMessages()) {
            qMessagesHelper.showQimobAlert(s);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        qMessagesHelper.toastWarning(null, e.getMessage(), null);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Método do Service que realiza calculo de valor pago e valor aberto e retorna o lançamento com novos valores setados nesses campos:

```java
public LancamentoFinanceiro addPagamento(LancamentoFinanceiro lancamento, Pagamento pagamentoAux) {
    switch (pagamentoAux.getMeioPagamento()) {
        case DINHEIRO:
            pagamentoAux.setSituacao(SituacaoLancamento.CONCILIADO);
            break;
        default:
            pagamentoAux.setSituacao(SituacaoLancamento.BAIXADO);
            break;
    }

    Integer index = isRepetido(pagamentoAux, lancamento);
    if (index != null) {
        lancamento.getPagamentos().get(index)
                .setValorPago(lancamento.getPagamentos().get(index).getValorPago()
                        .add(pagamentoAux.getValorPago()));
    } else {
        lancamento.addPagamento(pagamentoAux);
    }

    lancamento.getValoresLancamentosFinanceiro().setValorPago(lancamento.getValoresLancamentosFinanceiro().getValorPago()
            .add(pagamentoAux.getValorPago()));
    lancamento.getValoresLancamentosFinanceiro().setValorAberto(calculaVlrAberto(lancamento));

    return lancamento;
}
```

após realizar essa operação ele retorna para o Modal apresentado no primeiro código. O usuário tem a opção de Salvar, ou Cancelar. Se ele clica em salvar Ok, vai fazer todo o processo que quero e realiza o update no Banco. Porém mesmo eu cancelando, ou simplesmente clicando fora do Modal ele realiza o update do banco, mesmo não havendo nenhuma ação de persitencia/update associado a estas ações.

Entidade:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_lancamento_financeiro")
@XmlRootElement
public class LancamentoFinanceiro extends BaseEntity {
...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "lancamentoFinanceiro", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Pagamento> pagamentos;
...
}
```

Método de Update:

```java
    public void update(Object entity) throws RepositorioException, JaExisteException, NaoExisteException {
    if (entity == null) {
        throw new RepositorioException("Entidade informada é nula");
    } else {
        try {
            entityManager.merge(entity);
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            throw new NaoExisteException(e.getMessage());
        } catch (PersistenceException e) {
            Throwable t = e.getCause();
            while ((t != null) && !(t instanceof ConstraintViolationException)) {
                t = t.getCause();
            }

            if (t instanceof ConstraintViolationException) {
                throw new JaExisteException(e.getMessage());
            } else {
                throw new RepositorioException(e.getMessage());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RepositorioException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Você está usando o objeto do Hibernate diretamente na tela? O ideal seria ter um modelo para a tela (visão), que chamamos de ViewModel, e então após todas as validações do controller, seria atualizado o objeto Hibernate com os dados do novo objeto. Note que pode caso queira usar um objeto do Hibernate direto na interface, terá que controlar a sessão Hibernate **fora** da interface, para apenas dar o commit final após passar pelos métodos do controller. Contudo, sua pergunta carece de qualidade pois não possui um exemplo mínimo e viável para entender o contexto.

Comment: A estrutura é essa. Existe a entidade(Model) mapeada, a camada de controller e service. A questão é que ele simplesmente está ignorando todas as camadas e realizando o update direto no banco. Nem mesmo no método que meu EntityManager realiza o Merge ele passa.
Sobre o exemplo nem sei o que colocar pois ele já vai direto pra o banco, mas vou printar pelo menos onde ele deveria estar passando.

Comment: Jhonatan, você tem algum gerenciamento de sessão? Que tipo de aplicativo é? Usa algum framework? Um exemplo em .NET de gerenciamento de sessão no ASP.NET: http://joseoncode.com/2011/03/03/effective-nhibernate-session-management-for-web-apps/ . Portanto fica claro que é preciso saber que tipo de aplicação é (desktop, mobile, web) e o framework, se houver, sendo usado.

Comment: O projeto é Java web (JSF 2). Coloquei alguns trechos de código acima para ver se dá de melhor elucidar o problema.

Comment: Eu não acho que o problema esteja com suas classes em si, mas sim no gerenciamento de sessão do Hibernate. Como não tenho experiência em JSF não posso ajudar mais do que isso. Deve aparecer alguém com experiência nisso e, com nossa conversa e os novos dados que colocou na pergunta, devem conseguir te responder! Mas aposto, de novo, que o gerenciamento da sessão é o culpado disso aí!

Comment: Talvez uma dessas perguntas respondidas no Stack Overflow tenha sua resposta: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848769/is-this-a-right-pattern-for-hibernate-session-transaction-management , ou, 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23802226/hibernate-session-handling-when-using-lazy-loading-in-a-jsf-web-application

Comment: Obrigado. Vou conferir os links indicados.

Comment: Se ele faz o update na base de dados sem nem sequer passar pelo seu `bean` ou `controller` pode ser problema com a sessão do `Hibernate`. Já tive alguns problemas com sessões, transações, lazy load.. e outros com o `Hibernate` + `JSF`. A melhor solução foi trocar para [EclipseLink](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/%22EclipseLink%22). Obs: Seu código, tecnicamente, mantém o mesmo, já que é uma implementação do `JPA` como o `Hibernate`.